# How to pass default values for prompts in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a program that will prompt me to enter 'a', 'b' or 'c'. If I run the program manually, I can enter the choices when prompted. How can I handle the prompts when running the program with a batch file?

The program does not take any parameters.

Comment: If the program reads from standard input, you can write `echo a | whatever.exe`.

Comment: What version of DOS are you using?

Comment: @Squashman, windows 2012 r2

Comment: A `cmd.exe` prompt, despite appearances, has nothing to do with DOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your program reads the input from *STDIN*, you can use [input redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). There are two options:

1. Piping the output (at *STDOUT*) of an `echo` command into your `program.exe`:

   ```cmd
   echo a| program.exe
   ```

   You can even pipe multiple lines of `echo`:

   ```cmd
   (
       echo a
       echo b
       echo c
   ) | program.exe
   ```
2. Create a file, say `prompts.txt`, containing the prompt texts, one per line:

   > ```cmd
   > a
   > b
   > c
   > ```

   Then redirect that file:

   ```cmd
   < prompts.txt program.exe
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the variable to the default value first before asking the user for the value. This way, even if the user doesn't enter the value, you have the default value stored anyway.

SET myvar=a (guessing that a is the default value) would do the trick.

Comment: The OP does not ask for setting a variable in a batch script (`set /P`). See [@Bill-Stewart's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729312/how-to-pass-default-values-for-prompts-in-dos-batch#comment72578218_42729312)